# Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: service-pack

I have Windows Web Server 2008 R2 and i'm woundering if there is an Service Pack 2 to this edition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No (or rather, not yet).

Windows 2008 R2 is the server equivalent of Windows 7, so matches Windows 7 with service packs (as Server 2008 matches Vista).